# Laravel module wise unit test

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I have been using Pingpong modules in Laravel project. So there is one `Test` directory for each of the modules. But if I write the PHPUnit test case there, it is not executing as desired. It is only executing the test cases in the root Test folder. Is there any configuration change I need to make for executing the module wise test cases ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add this to your phpunit.xml file:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <testsuite name="Modules Test Suite">
            <directory>./Modules/*/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

This way, when you run the whole test suite, it will execute the tests inside each Tests folder within each module.